# Python setup.py to import python file

Tags: python, python-2.7

I try to write a package called 'fraud' using setup.py

```
from setuptools import setup

setup(name='fraud',
      version='0.1',
      install_requires=[
          'gremlinpython==3.3.3',
      ],
      py_modules=['fraud.graph2j',
                  'fraud.config'],
      entry_points = {
          'console_scripts': [
              'graph2j=fraud.graph2j:main',
          ]
      })
```

The python file graph2j.py contains

```
from . import config
import argparse
import os

def main():
    print "Hey it works!"
```

I notice that when i run

```
python setup.py install
```

The *config.py* is copied to *build/lib/fraud/* , and when I run

```
graph2j
```

I get

```
Hey it works!
```

I am wondering if there is a way to NOT copy *config.py* to *build/lib/fraud/* and without specifying *py_modules* in setup.py? For now, if I remove *'fraud.config'* from py_modules, I'd get the following error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/[bla]/anaconda2/bin/graph2janus", line 11, in <module>
     load_entry_point('fraud==0.1', 'console_scripts', 'graph2j')()
   File "/Users/[bla]/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-     packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 480, in load_entry_point
     return get_distribution(dist).load_entry_point(group, name)
   File "/Users/[bla]/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-     packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2691, in load_entry_point
     return ep.load()
   File "/Users/[bla]/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-     packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2322, in load
     return self.resolve()
        File "/Users/[bla]/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-     packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py", line 2328, in resolve
     module = __import__(self.module_name, fromlist=['__name__'], level=0)
   File "build/bdist.macosx-10.6-x86_64/egg/fraud/graph2j.py", line 1, in <module>
 ImportError: cannot import name config
```

Answer (score 0):

When you say 'copy all my custom python files to the lib,' do you mean import them? If so, you can just use:

```
import config
```

If you don't want the config to run till called, then add

```
if "__name__" == "__main__":
```

so that it will only run when whatever is inside the config is called.

I hope this helped!